# Placing a ladder to maximize the sum of height and length

Tags: calculus

> For which $\theta$ is $x+y$ maximal?
>
> [image]

What I have done is $\tan(\theta)=\frac{x}{y}$, so $x=y \cdot \tan(\theta)$.

If $f(x)=y+y\cdot \tan(\theta)$, then $f'(x)=1+\tan(\theta)$, and so $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $y$ is itself a function of $\theta$, so the $f'$ that you have is incorrect.

Comment: Presumably you are given the length $L$ of the ladder, and you want to maximize $x+y$. If that is the case, it should be made clear in the question. Then you can proceed *somewhat* like you did, $x=L\sin\theta, y=\dots$.

Comment: No length is needed. Any abitrary length will have the same $\theta $ for the maximum value of $x+y $. However it is helpful to introduce a variable for the length.

Answer (score 1):

Say your ladder is length $L$. Then $y=L\cos(\theta) $ and $x=L\sin (\theta) $ therefore
$f(\theta)=x+y=L\cos(\theta)+L\sin(\theta)$.
Then to maximize this we take the derivative and set it to zero.
$f'(\theta)=L (\cos (\theta)-\sin(\theta))=0$ 
therefore it is maximized when $\cos (\theta)=\sin(\theta) $ which means $\theta=\frac {\pi}{4} $
**Note to OP:**
After you rephrased the question, it is a little hard understand the context of my answer. However, if you still are interested in knowing what $\theta$ maximizes the sum of $x$ and $y$, my answer provides the solution to that.

Comment: why $L(cos(\theta)-sin(\theta))?$

Comment: @gbox to take the derivative, first pull out the common factor of $L $. Then take the derivate of $\sin (\theta) + \cos (\theta) $ which is $\cos (\theta) - \sin(\theta) $

Comment: Correction: made a typo. Meant to say $\theta=\pi/4$ not $\pi/2$